# Recover deleted notebook on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I accidentally deleted a jupyter notebook file on my AWS Sagemaker instance. I wonder if there's anyway to restore/recover the file?

Comment: Did you check {notebook_directory}/.ipynb_checkpoints/ for a snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first check `{notebook_directory}/.ipynb_checkpoints/` for a snapshot.. the directory should contain copies of your notebooks from the point in time when they were last saved.

If that's gone, the IPython kernel saves commands issued to it in a sqlite db. found in `~/.ipython/profile_default`. There you should find ***history.sqlite***.

history.sqlite should contain all commands issued to the ipython kernel. Tables of interest are **sessions** and **history**.

You need to query the sessions table by session start or end time to determine which sessions are related to the ones you're looking for:

```
select 
    sessions.session, sessions.start, sessions.end, history.source
from sessions 
join history using (session)
where
    start > 'your_start_date' and start < 'your_end_date';
```

once you find your session:

```
select '# @@ Cell '|| line || char(10) || source || char(10) from history where session = your_session_number;
```

Output your query to .py then use jupytext to convert to ipynb, then you have your notebook back:

```
sqlite3 history.sqlite \
    "select '# @@ Cell '|| line || char(10) || source || char(10)    from history where session = your_session_number;" \
> output.py
```

Answer (score 5):

One option that you could try if you accidentally deleted the file from the Jupyter lab side tab, is to:

1. open a system terminal
2. navigate to `cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files/`
3. run `ls` to list the deleted files and check if the file is in there.
4. Then just simply move it back to your sagemakers home directory (or wherever you want) --> `mv deleted-file.ipynb /home/sagemaker-user/`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to recover the history with by executing below command in a notebook cell.

```
%history -g
```