# Recover deleted AWS Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I think I may have accidentally deleted a notebook in my Sagemaker instance, is there a way to recover it? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300737/recover-deleted-notebook-on-aws-sagemaker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover deleted notebook on AWS Sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300737/recover-deleted-notebook-on-aws-sagemaker)